# How to trim audio file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, trim

I have sound files in my document directory folder and i want to trim that sound file.
How to do that?

Comment: You want to do that on run time?

Comment: can you show us what you have done and where you are getting problems? this is not write my code for me site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Extended Audio File Services. have a look at the reference for ExtAudioFileRead & ExtAudioFileWrite (they have sample code) then you can open one audio file read it, trim it and then write the new one.go here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I don't find sample code for ExtAudioFileRead & ExtAudioFileWrite!

Comment: @AppleDeveloper pls see "Related Sample Code" heading in that page buddy.pls do slowly.u can do perfectly

Comment: @AppleDeveloper for instant help go here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop