# Merge audio/video when audio duration is less than video duration

Tags: ios, merge, avmutablecomposition

I'm only merging a single audio/video file. The problem is that, my video file is of 40 seconds & audio file is of 28 seconds. So for remaining 12 (40 - 28) seconds – I want to repeat audio for the remaining part from 0 second. How do I that? Is there a direct way to do this?

P.S. I'm using AVComposition for this. And code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169495/4596420).

Comment: Have you tired to call `insertTimeRange:ofTrack:atTime:` several times with time ranges that goes one after another?

Comment: @Sega-Zero, no I called it for once only.

Comment: [The code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65338627/1320392) for that answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the time of both video and audio which i guess you were able to do it. if audio is lesser that video crop the audio using the code mentioned in the [How to trim audio file in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303264/how-to-trim-audio-file-in-iphone). Do follow the same and then merge the audio files [Combine two audio files into one in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519814/combine-two-audio-files-into-one-in-objective-c) and then do what you want.

Comment: This is something that I am thinking.. but don't you think, this will put extra overhead on to the code? Is there any direct way for this? However +1 for the good suggestion.